# How to correctly set up React Router with multilanguage/multiple index.html files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm building a web app, with latest React and React Router version, in my case my app supports many languages, and due to indexing, we have separate entry html files for each language. So for a url like this myapp.com, we would have

*myapp.com/en/* - for english

*myapp.com/de/* - for german etc...

On the server side each of these */en/* folders would of course have their own *index.html* file with **meta**, **title** and other metadata written in the given language and they all have entry to our React app (*bundle.js*)

I already built something like this previously with Router Hash History, so my app looked like myapp.com/en/#/home, and my main route in *routes.js* of course looked like this

```
<Route path="/" component={MainComponent}
```

Now I want to use BrowserRouter, and I want my routes to look like this
if the url is *myapp.com/en/*
the link would be:

```
<Link to="/home" />
```

And once clicked it would take you to *myapp.com/en/home* and it would render correctly the Compnent that is linked to it in the Route

```
 <Route path="/home" exact component={HomeContainer} />
```

Basically at the moment this would only work if I did something like this

```
<Link to=`/${getCurrentLanguage()}/home` /
```

and the route is like this

```
<Route path=`/${getCurrentLanguage()}/home` exact component={HomeContainer} />
```

Which is maddness of course,

How can I achieve the desired behavior or do you have any different approach in mind? thanks

**edit** I'm not asking anything about React translations, I will be using i18next for translating the React side, I'm asking about the problem of Routing with different index.html files

Comment: How different are the sites? Are there any differences beyond the language of the text? If not, you should probably use something like https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl

Comment: hi thanks for commenting, I'm talking about static index.html file, the translation on React side will be done with i18next, that's not the problem, the problem is how to handle navigation with BrowserRouter and having multiple index.html files

Comment: You can just match the url https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/match.md

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways one can approach this

1. Setting BrowserRouter basename property to the given language

```js
<BrowserRouter basename=`/${getLanguage()}`>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    </Switch>
< /BrowserRouter>
```

So you can navigate freely with `<Link to="/about" />`

2. or use /:lng before any other route

```js
<Switch>
    <Route path="/:lng/" exact component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Where is the `getLanguage()` coming from?

Comment: Where was the function defined?

Comment: Its abstraction. You can use `react-i18next`, `react-intl` or something similar.