# nested routes with optional parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi there for localization reasion i need optional nested routes like /en/mypage  , /ru/mypage , /my page, I already tried to work with `<Route` but didn't get it working.

```
<Route path="/:lang(en|lt|ru)?" >
   <Route path="/surveys" exact component={Dashboard} />
</Route>
```

Already found solutions above with earlier versions but it doesn't seem working now. How can i implement it? i know it's posible to add to every route parameter, but isn't here more elegant way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49004533/how-to-correctly-set-up-react-router-with-multilanguage-multiple-index-html-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest your routes in React-Router v4. Instead you should add nested routes in `component` or use `render` prop:

```
<Route path="/:lang(en|lt|ru)" render={({ match: { url } }) => (
      <>
        <Route path={`${url}/surveys`} component={Dashboard} exact />
      </>
    )} 
/>
```

In above example your available routes would be

```
/en/surveys
/lt/surveys
/ru/surveys
```